# Should I remove GA/GDN code if I'm using GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Does GTM code + GA/GDN Tag is enough to track my website analytics ? should I remove GA code if I'm using GTM ?

And aboud google adwords goals , should I remove Google adwords code too and use that one provided from GTM ?

Answer (score 1):

> Does GTM code + GA/GDN Tag is enough to track my website analytics ?

Yes, if you have configured the GA tracking tag in the tag manager you do not any other GA code on your site.

> should I remove GA code if I'm using GTM

Yes. You do not need it anymore and if you do not remove it you might track your pages and event twice.

> And aboud google adwords goals , should I remove Google adwords code
>   too and use that one provided from GTM

While it is still possible to use the Adwords code side by side with the tag manager it does not make any sense. As a matter of elegance and maintainability I'd say YES, you should remove page code and use GTM instead. Having all tags in one location is after all the point of GTM.